# False timestamps on files

Tags: timestamp

So I was wondering how the touch command really worked. I found `touch -t` which seems to modify the timestamp based on a string of numbers, but how is this string formatted? Can this be used to falsify the creation, access, or modify time on a file? Is it that simple?

Also, `ls -lh` only shows the date and time of day for me yet I see that for some other people it shows the year too. Why? How do I get it to show the year?

Comment: On your second question, it's not other people it's other dates. `ls -l` traditionally and standardly displays Mon dd hh:mm if the time is within the last 6 months and Mon dd yyyy (no time!) if older. `-h` implies GNU ls (perhaps Linux) which has (several!) additional options you might prefer: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Formatting-file-timestamps.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/74667/how-to-use-touch-to-create-empty-files-and-modify-timestamps/):

> The stamp is [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]. [CC] is for century and you may
>   ignore it and ignore the seconds as well. If you ignore [CC] the
>   command will substitute it depending on what you enter as year. If you
>   specify the year with only two digits, then CC is 20 for years in the
>   range (0~68) and 19 for years in (69~99).

This is indeed sometimes used to falsify timestamps and make it harder when investigating a compromised machine to find altered files or added binaries.

Comment: So this actually would impact the ability of security professionals to investigate a machine? If I `touch -t` a file right now except make it June 13, they can't prove that it is possible for that file to have last been accessed or modified today?

Comment: Yep, proof is also relative.

Comment: Nice literature here, you should take a look: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/11/linux-touch-command/